# Want to install Jruby but intimidated by RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

Want to install Jruby and I am pretty sure that I want to manage it with RVM.  My problem is that I am a little intimidated by RVM with its command line and all the dependencies (bash, git, etc.) I am on Windows 7, ruby 1.9.3.
Can someone please help a newbie out and explain this in English.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RVM is not supported on windows.

```
"If you would like to manage multiple versions of ruby on windows please use pik which is an excellent tool by Gordon Thiesfeld. You can find it on GitHub."
```

Options to manage ruby version over windows:

1. pik is a tool to manage multiple versions of ruby on Windows. It can be used from the Windows command line (cmd.exe), Windows PowerShell, or Git Bash. [Github-pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik)
2. You can also use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and then install the various packages required.
   Checkout

   [How to install rvm on windows using cygwin](http://www.tiplite.com/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-using-cygwin/)

I would recommend using linux/mac OS when working with open source.

Comment: pik wrks well, for me, in Windows, to switch between different versions of ruby and jruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install ruby on Windows I suggest you to use [PIK](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/pik/). It's sponsored by RubyInstaller.

And, about install Jruby on Windows ... all that you have to do is go to JRuby website and download the **.exe file**.

JRuby Website Link here: http://jruby.org/download

Comment: I did use pik back when I was still using Windows. It worked somewhat well, but there were some bugs. Those have been fixed for over a year now, but the last release was *two* years ago!